# How to set the template context for reactive form?

Tags: angular

I have groups of `FormGroup`, called `fgList`,initialized in the *component*. As such:

```
const fgList = [
    new FormGroup({ /* ... */),
    new FormGroup({ /* ... */)
];
```

For the template, I want to use ***ngFor** associate with the **ng-template**, is it possible?

```
<div *ngFor="let fg of fgList">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="colorText; context: fg"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #colorText>
    <span class="red">{{ fg.get('name').value }}</div>
</ng-template>
```

It keeps saying that *can't read property 'get' of undefined*. May I know how to pass the `fg` and use it inside the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should declare `fg` variable in template

```
<div *ngFor="let fg of fgList">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="colorText; context:{instance:fg}"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #colorText let-fg="instance"> <!-- access context here -->
    <span class="red">{{ fg.get('name').value }}</div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

because of your ***ngFor** if closed.

try to use below code:

```js
<div *ngFor="let fg of fgList">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="colorText; context: fg"></ng-container>


<ng-template #colorText>
    <span class="red">{{ fg.get('name').value }}</div>
</ng-template>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to put my **ng-template** at other place? I want to organize my HTML code so that all reusable template are written at the bottom of my code?

Comment: yes, it is possible, create a new component and define the templates in the respective component with the help of TemplateRef and ContentChildren. 
Do you have any idea about TemplateRef, ContentChildren?

Comment: i will try to read it... so, in other words, I *can't* set `context` and make all available external variables visible inside the the template?

Comment: you can set the context dynamically, do you want to generate the dynamic form?

Comment: Hmmm, I have a lengthy HTML code, and want to shorten the main code by moving partial of the code inside the templates, and place those templates at the bottom of my code. Hmmm, thinking of a way to shorten my main code and enhanced readability, while trying not to sacrifice the performance. Thinking that using extra component for `templateRef` and `contentChildren` will sacrifice the performance, so hope to use the easiest `ng-tempate` approach...

Comment: can you please share some more information about your form, So that I will create sample application to give more understanding.

Comment: thanks. Just read https://blog.angularindepth.com/use-ng-template-c72852c37fba, and it solve the problem. Use the `let-templatevar="inputvar"`, and it can find those variables.

Comment: Ok, Thanks Boo Yan Jiong